# user control 2 listener failing

Tags: events, user-controls, event-handling, event-listener

I have 1 web form and multiple user controls. One of the user controls fires an event. The page is listening and gets the value the control sends out. However the other user controls listening attach to the event but never get to the method.

User Control 1

```
public delegate void GetOrgIdEventHandler(long orgId);

public event GetOrgIdEventHandler GetOrgId;

protected void gvSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GetOrgId != null)
    {
        GetOrgId(Id);
    }
}
```

Web Form

```
//Search1 is the Id of the User Control on the web form - This is working. 
//It calls the method in the assignment
Search1.GetOrgId += 
new SearchGridViewSelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(GetTheOrgId);
```

User Control 2

```
//SearchUserControl is the name of the User Control 2 Class
protected SearchUserControl mySuc = new SearchUserControl();

//The line below works, however the method does not get called. This is where it fails.
//I set a breakpoint in GetTheOrgId but I never get to that break.
mySuc.GetOrgId += new SearchGridViewSelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(GetTheOrgId);
```

Comment: Is it possible to send an event from one user control to another user control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can raise events in the first control, have it picked up in the parent, and then have the parent call a method/function in the second control.  Example (in VB.Net):

User control one:

> Partial Class user_controls_myControl
>       Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
>
> ```
>  Public Event DataChange As EventHandler
>
>  'now raise the event somewhere, for instance when the page loads:
>
>  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
>      RaiseEvent DataChange(Me, New EventArgs)
> end sub
>   end Class
> ```

This will raise an event, called DataChange, when the control loads.  Or, you can raise it in response to another event withing the controls (like if a button gets pushed).  This will raise an event that the parent can subscibe to, like this (assuming you have a control on the page called MyControl1):

Main Page:

```
Protected Sub myControl_dataChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) handles myControl1.DataChange
```

End Sub

Now, you can then expose a method in your second control, like this:

```
Partial Class user_controls_myOtherControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    public sub callMe()
       'do something
    end Sub

end Class
```

You can then call the method in the second control, from the parent page, like this:

```
me.userConrol2.callMe()
```

If you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing prior to the weekend. Thanks a lot for your answer.